# How do I make a custom keyboard button to dismiss

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

How do I make a button to dismiss keyboard 
the key is located above the keyboard? 
custom keyboard

```
 var button: UIButton = UIButton()

required init(globalColors: GlobalColors.Type?, darkMode: Bool, solidColorMode: Bool) {
    super.init(globalColors: globalColors, darkMode: darkMode, solidColorMode: solidColorMode)
    self.addSubview(self.button)


    button.setTitle("Hide", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("tappedbutton"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 24.0/100, green: 116.0/255, blue: 205.0/205, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal)


 self.updateAppearance()

}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
     self.button.frame.origin = CGPointMake(self.button.frame.origin.x + self.button.frame.width + 1, self.button.frame.origin.y)

}
```